# using odbc to connect to Oracle database in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I'm trying to write a tool in c# which will connect to Oracle database and I'm required to use ODBC.

If I use the following code:

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
string str1 = "DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abcd.efgh.net)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)));USER ID=user_id;PASSWORD=qassword";
OdbcConnection coon = new OdbcConnection();
coon.ConnectionString = str1;
coon.Open();
```

I get the error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

even if I change the connection string to:

```
string str2 = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12home1};DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abcd.efgh.net)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)));USER ID=user_id;PASSWORD=qassword";
```

I get the same error message.
So I guess the problem is not the "Driver = {...}" part? But what did I get wrong in the "DATA SOURCE" part?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you configured the ODBC connection on the machine the application is running on?

Comment: I tested the connection with ODBC Data Source Administrator, and the connection was successful. Is this what you mean?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: What is the architecture of your application, 32 bit (x86) or 64 bit (x64)? Is it the same as your Oracle client, resp. ODBC driver?

Comment: It seems that the application (Visual Studio) us 32 bit..... Well, at least I have some clue to try out. Thank you.

Comment: Visual Studio is always 32 bit, but what did you set in compile options?

Comment: I followed every step in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32, hoping that 32-64-bit issue could be solved.But didn't work..

Comment: I changed the driver to datadirect 7.1 oracle wire protocol, and that one worked. connection string = "DRIVER={DataDirect 7.1 Oracle Wire Protocol};HOST=server1;PORT=1522;
UID=JOHN;PWD=XYZZY;SERVICENAME=SALES.US.ACME.COM"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        using System.Data.Odbc;

        String connectionString = "Dsn=HP5ODBC;uid=system;pwd=manager";          
        OdbcConnection coon = new OdbcConnection();
        coon.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        coon.Open();
        MessageBox.Show(coon.State.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient12home1};DBQ={(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abcd.efgh.net)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))};UID=user_id;PWD=qassword";
```

instead of

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient12home1};DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abcd.efgh.net)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)));USER ID=user_id;PASSWORD=qassword";
```

See [Using the Oracle ODBC Driver: Format of the Connection String](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183) and/or [Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/)

Comment: Did you verify the architecture (32 vs. 64 bit)?

Comment: I believe I installed 64bit for all oracle client/database... But how to double check the architecture?